# Not able to get Server result of processing request.params in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am learning about epxressjs request object and while experimenting with the request.params when I run the following curl commands on terminal :
$ curl http://localhost:3000/params/admin/azat/active
$ curl http://localhost:3000/params/user/bob/active

I am not getting the server result.

My server is running on port 3000.

```
 app.get('/params/:role/:name/:status', function(req, res) {
 console.log(req.params);
 res.end();
 });
```

expected results must be this on server :
{role: 'admin', name:'azat' status:'active'} 
{role: 'user', name:'bob' status:'active'}

Comment: What are you getting instead?

Comment: Nothing I am getting a blank page on server.

Comment: Blank page on server or the browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the response of the curl to be the params, try this:

```
 app.get('/params/:role/:name/:status', function(req, res) {
   res.json(req.params);
 });
```